# How is this edit incorrect?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3017727), and it was rejected for two reasons:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.`

and

> This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.`

Is that title acceptable on Stack Overflow and why is the edit an attempt to reply to or comment on the post?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think the original title was the worst part of the post:

> Essentials C# framework 3.5 book from Mark Michaelis, errors in code from the book

And I especially don't think your title change was good:

> Error using List

In fact, I think the suggested title made the post worse as it said nothing about the actual issue.

If I clicked a question with the title you proposed (if I even opened it because it doesn't sound interesting), I would have expected someone actually getting an error related to using a list and not because of a method missing a return value.

So in this case both of the reject reasons you received are valid (emphasis mine)

- "This edit is **incorrect** or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post."
- **This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.**

But had you not touched the title, the "Too Minor" reject reason might have come into play since you left a lot of issues as [Aaron](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198599/182513) has identified.

Comment: I guess that was my major mistake

Comment: And "changes too much" fits fairly well to reject this.

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi Aaron's answer is also very important.  When suggesting edits, fix everything, don't just pick and choose, but it was the title change that made it "Incorrect" and "Changes too much"

Comment: In fact, when I clicked on the review link, I hadn't even noticed the title had been changed; I focused on the changes that were made to the body (and more importantly the ones that weren't).

Answer (score 12):

You changed a title from something that actually tells me a fair bit about the post to something that tells me almost nothing about the post.  It's quite a bit worse than the previous one, which makes both rejection reasons entirely justified.

Your new title doesn't even make sense.  There is no `List` in his code for him to have problems with.  In addition to being very vague and unhelpful, it's not even *accurate*.

As Aaron has said, you also didn't improve as much as I'd like to see in the body of the post, but that's less of a problem than making a title dramatically *worse*.

I have [edited the post myself](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19052135/2).  You can take a look at it to see all of the problems with the post that you didn't address, and how I've shortened the title a bit without removing *helpful* information from it.

Answer (score 8):

Well, you made a few grammatical corrections, but you didn't fix some other obvious ones, e.g.

> Im new
>   
> havent putt
>   
> i will be happy

You also could have put the error message in a blockquote:

> 'xxxx.ConsoleListControl.DisplayHeader(string[])': not all code path returns a value.

Suggested edits are often rejected if they don't fix *everything* in the post...

Comment: While I agree; thats opposite to the reject reasons chosen which are of the "too much" flavour

Comment: Oh ok but these are not the reasons why the edit was rejected

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi: Some people pick the wrong reject reason, unfortunately. (Although the title might have had something to do with it, too.)

Comment: Rejection *reason* was wrong. Rejection itself was just.

Comment: @minitech I guess so.

Comment: I was thinking people might have been upset about the major title change

Comment: @minitech Is that type of title accepted in stack overflow?

Comment: @RichardTingle may be, may be, but at the same time old title contains a lot of simply unneeded data

Comment: @Mołot The title could be improved sure, but this edit didn't improve it.  If it shortened a bit without reducing its value then it could be fine.

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi the title you changed it to was far too terse to be useful.

Comment: @AaronBertrand And also just wrong, not just too short, which is far worse.